# Can't find user by email using GraphAPI

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I'm using GraphAPI getting users by email for months. Something happened to a specific user. Right now I can't get this user using the following approach:

`signInNames/any(x:x/value eq '{email}'`

This is working with all users excepting the one I said before.

I'm getting this when trying to retrieve by email:

```
{ 
  "odata.metadata": "https://graph.windows.net/jsmaddev.onmicrosoft.com/$metadata#directoryObjects", 
  "value":[]
}
```

If I try to get by ObjectId I can access user's info but the signInNames seems to be empty:

```
"signInNames":[]
```

Is there something that could cause this? You should remember that this particular access was working as intended.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal. The filter `signInNames/any(x:x/value eq '{email}'` returns the users whose `signInNames.value` equals the email.

The `signInNames` part sample:

```
 "signInNames": [
    {
      "type": "userName",
      "value": "AlexW"
    },
    {
      "type": "emailAddress",
      "value": "AlexW@example.com"
    }
  ]
```

> If I try to get by ObjectId I can access user's info but the signInNames seems to be empty

Since the `signInNames` property is empty, `"signInNames":[]`, it will returns the `"value":[]`.

[image]

> You should remember that this particular access was working as intended.

Of course, if the `signInNames` is not empty, it will work fine.

[image]

Comment: Right but as I said this user was working as intended and suddenly stopped. Is there anything that could cause this? Thanks!

Comment: @AustinFelipe Not sure, there may be someone in your tenant update the property of the user. You could navigate to the Azure Active Directory in the portal -> Users -> Audit logs, check the logs, specific the Target with the object id of the user, see : https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwIl0.png, for more details about audit logs, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-audit-logs). In short, the comment above is just my guess. For this question, actually you should not ask me, you should ask the members in your tenant.